# fetch formdata response from php server

Tags: javascript, php, fetch, response

I understand that fetch() response lets you receive formData from a server. I searched for an example that implements this functionality but I didn't find a single one. All examples talk about uploading (posting) formData from a client to a server, but not vice versa. This doesn't explain the .formData() method of the response.

So, could you please direct me to any link that has an example that receives a form data from a PHP server using the .formData() method of a fetch() response.

Thank you

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/formData shows the basic idea. But it's very unusual for a server to return stuff in formData format - I've never seen that happen. It's not actually a very convenient format when it's serialised. Normally a server would return plain text, HTML, JSON or XML (or binary file data, of course). Have you actually come across this situation, or are you thinking of programming your server to do that? IMHO it would be a lot easier to use JSON in the response, for example - there's a good reason it's very popular. And fetch can read it easily too.

Comment: ok. but what is this '.formData()' method is used for then?

Comment: Why did they add a method that almost nobody needs?

Comment: The "note" in yellow at the top of the documentation I provided explains what it's mainly used for. (It's important to realise that this can read from the body of an outgoing _request_ as as well as an incoming response. And also, "almost nobody" isn't the same as "nobody" - if _somebody_ needs it then it's useful. Even 1% of all web developers is still thousands of people!)

Comment: Thank you for your patience. As I understood from your explanation and the yellow note, this method is going in the opposite direction of the other fetch response's methods (text, json, blob). While those methods read a response from a server, the formData() method reads/intercepts a request/response while it is on the way to the server. really unusual. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes it's unusual - but as it explains a service worker might need it in order to modify the request, or for some other purpose. It does happen. Also, please understand that the text(), json() blob() etc methods can all be used in both directions too - these methods are attached to the Body object. Both requests and responses can contain a Body. So actually these methods don't care if it's a request or a response, they simply try to read from the Body of whatever it happens to be.

Comment: how do you mark this question as 'solved' ?

Comment: I've now added an answer, so please check if you're happy with it as a summary of our discussion, and if so then please mark it accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/formData demonstrates the basic idea:

```
response.formData()
.then(function(formdata) {
  // do something with your formdata
});
```

But it's very unusual for a server to return data in formData format - I've never seen that happen. It's not actually a very convenient format when it's serialised. Normally a server will return plain text, HTML, JSON or XML (or binary file data, of course).

The "note" in yellow at the top of the documentation explains what it's mainly used for. It says:

> This is mainly relevant to service workers. If a user submits a form
> and a service worker intercepts the request, you could for example
> call formData() on it to obtain a key-value map, modify some fields,
> then send the form onwards to the server (or use it locally).

(It's important to realise that this can read from the body of an outgoing request as as well as an incoming response. And also that the comparable `text()`, `json()` `blob()` etc methods can all be used in both directions too - these methods are attached to the Body object. Both requests and responses can contain a Body. So actually these methods don't care if it's a request or a response, they simply try to read from the Body of whatever it happens to be.)